# How to hook up a fan to this switching circuit

Tags: transistors, switches, raspberry-pi, breadboard

I am trying to build a controlable fan with a raspberry pi and I have found the below circuit for a switching circuit to allow the 12V power to go to the fan

[image]

My question is how do I then hook the fan up to this for it to recieve the 12V power. Am I missing something?

The current and everything i have checked, i just need help with physically wiring up the fan.

Comment: The circuit shown will probably just work with 3V3 on the base of Q2 though...

Comment: This is not the right way to go about things. You need to start with the specifications of the fan. Not all 12V fans are created equal. They vary considerably in the current required. This will affect the transistor you choose. They vary in the interface: 2-wire, 3-wire, 4-wire, which affects how you should drive them. Please edit your question with a datasheet for the fan.

Comment: If they're going to use a common computer fan, and don't need the tachometer or speed control, they can all be run with just the first two pins.

Comment: I cant find a datasheet but it is literally just a 12V rated fan with a positive and negative wire

Comment: In addition to the voltage spec, you also need to know the current the motor draws from the power supply when the motor is on.

Comment: Overly complicated.  Just use the 3904 to switch the low side of the fan (provided the 3904 can handle the required current.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You connect the fan between "12V out" and ground.

Q2 is configured as a switchable current sink.  With 5 V on its base, its emitter will be at about 4.3 V.  That causes 1 mA thru R2.  Most of that will come from the collector, which in turn means it comes from the base of Q1.  That current being drawn out of the base of Q1 turns it on.  That switches the "12V out" line high.  Its voltage will be the 12 V input voltage minus the C-E drop of Q1.  For a saturated transistor without excessive current, that is usually around 200 mV.

You should check that the 2N3906 can handle the fan current.

Comment: Could you by any chance kind of give me a picture of that?

Comment: Is the arrow at the bottom ground?

Comment: @Tom: Yes, the down-pointing triangle is the ground symbol.